# sql result only with numeric values

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to create an sql query, which gives back only numeric results.

I tried this, but it did't work for me:

```
select *
from crm.Communication cm
where cm.TypeKey = 4 and data like '%[^0-9]%'
```

I don't want the result when there is one alphanumeric value.

Hope you guys can help me.

Bg,
France

Comment: Please provide table schema. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "it did't work for me" Is not a problem description. Why didn't it work? Did it throw an error? If so, what was the error? Did it not return expected results? What did it return, and what did you expect?

Comment: You want "not like a-z".

Comment: Isn't `[^0-9]` regular expression syntax?

Comment: use not like '%[^0-9]%'

Answer (score 1):

can you try this ?

```
select *
from crm.Communication cm
where cm.TypeKey = 4 and  ceil(data) = data
```

and if you want to use REGEXP

you need like this remove like and put REGEXP

```
select *
from crm.Communication cm
where cm.TypeKey = 4 and data REGEXP '[^0-9]'
```

Comment: Can you describe what happens here? (I don't know MySQL.)

Comment: @jarlh What happens is that you cannot dump regular expressions in arbitrary SQL functions—it's only possible in those that actually expect them.

Comment: @krishnpatel `%` in a regular expression means exactly that, `%`.

Answer (score -1):

Use NOT as well

```
select *
from crm.Communication cm
where cm.TypeKey = 4 and data not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using the correct regex but instead of using regular expression you are using like. Use `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE` like this:

```
select *
from crm.Communication cm
where cm.TypeKey = 4 and data REGEXP '%[^0-9]%'
```